# Error while reconnecting RabbitMQ node to the cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

We have a 3 node RabbitMQ cluster with nodes `A`, `B` and `C`

To test the failure scenarios, we stopped the service on node `A` with the command: `systemctl stop rabbitmq-server.service`

Then on Node `B` we ran the following command: `rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@A`

After this when we are trying to bring up the service on node `A` we get an error:

```
[root@A ~]# systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So to get this working we did the following:

```
[root@A ~]# rabbitmqctl stop_app
Stopping rabbit application on node rabbit@A ...
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@A'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@A
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@A']

rabbit@A:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on A
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on A
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-672-rabbit@A'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: qLO74L2PYI4QpJ2CDyQZBw==

[root@A ~]# rabbitmqctl reset
Resetting node rabbit@A ...

17:38:54.144 [warning] Feature flags: the previous instance of this node must have failed to write the `feature_flags` file at `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@A-feature_flags`:

17:38:54.144 [warning] Feature flags:   - list of previously disabled feature flags now marked as such: [:drop_unroutable_metric, :empty_basic_get_metric]
Error:
{{:badmap, :undefined}, [{:maps, :get, [:depends_on, :undefined, []], [file: 'maps.erl', line: 188]}, {:rabbit_feature_flags, :enable_dependencies, 2, [file: 'rabbit_feature_flags.erl', line: 1564]}, {:rabbit_feature_flags, :do_enable_locally, 1, [file: 'rabbit_feature_flags.erl', line: 1544]}, {:rabbit_feature_flags, :do_sync_feature_flags_with_node, 1, [file: 'rabbit_feature_flags.erl', line: 2174]}, {:rabbit_feature_flags, :sync_feature_flags_with_cluster1, 2, [file: 'rabbit_feature_flags.erl', line: 2144]}, {:rabbit_mnesia, :ensure_feature_flags_are_in_sync, 2, [file: 'rabbit_mnesia.erl', line: 645]}, {:rabbit_mnesia, :init_db, 3, [file: 'rabbit_mnesia.erl', line: 574]}, {:rabbit_mnesia, :init_db_and_upgrade, 4, [file: 'rabbit_mnesia.erl', line: 585]}]}
[root@A ~]# systemctl start rabbitmq-server
[root@A ~]# sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app
Stopping rabbit application on node rabbit@A ...
[root@A ~]# sudo rabbitmqctl reset
Resetting node rabbit@A ...
[root@A ~]# rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@B
Clustering node rabbit@A with rabbit@B

17:39:52.964 [warning] Feature flags: the previous instance of this node must have failed to write the `feature_flags` file at `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@A-feature_flags`:

17:39:52.964 [warning] Feature flags:   - list of previously disabled feature flags now marked as such: [:maintenance_mode_status]

17:39:53.660 [error] Failed to create a tracked connection table for node :"rabbit@A": {:node_not_running, :"rabbit@A"}

17:39:53.661 [error] Failed to create a per-vhost tracked connection table for node :"rabbit@A": {:node_not_running, :"rabbit@A"}

17:39:53.661 [error] Failed to create a per-user tracked connection table for node :"rabbit@A": {:node_not_running, :"rabbit@A"}
[root@A ~]# sudo rabbitmqctl start_app
Starting node rabbit@A ...
[root@A ~]#
```

Although the node joined back with the cluster, why did it give error while performing a `reset`? Also after running the `join_cluster` command, it gave out errors, but still it did connect to the cluster as we can see it as green in the management UI. Are the steps that we followed correct?

Comment: Which version of RabbitMQ are you using?

Comment: @LukeBakken RabbitMQ 3.10.6

Comment: I could not reproduce the warnings/errors on `rabbitmqctl reset` using the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to start with, your original test of ...

- stopped the service on node A with the command: `systemctl stop rabbitmq-server.service`
- on Node B we ran the following command: `rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@A`
- After this when we are trying to bring up the service on node A we get an error:

...is behaving as expected, since node A still thinks it is part of the cluster when you attempt to start it. This is the case even though you told the rest of the cluster (nodes B and C) to forget node A.

Then, you ran `rabbitmqctl stop_app` on node A, which also failed, because RabbitMQ was not running (due to the above).

I could not reproduce the error you saw with `rabbitmqctl reset`.

Finally, Stack Overflow isn't a very good place to discuss RabbitMQ issues or questions. I suggest using the official free support channels going forward:

- https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users
- https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions